# Picasso Images not loading with USB debugging, but working fine during emulation

Tags: debugging, kotlin, usb, picasso, drawerlayout

Issue: When using a Navigation Drawer Activity, Picasso loads images during emulation, but not during USB debugging... Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: SOLUTION In Answer!

Here's an image of my phone not showing the image, and the emulator working fine. I'm using a YouTube thumbnail as an online test image:
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/7876/4sd4ak.jpg

I noticed this in a larger project I was working on when I decided to whip it out on my phone, but in searching for the solution was able to isolate it to a fresh Navigation Drawer Layout Activity.

Here's what I know:

- All my SDK, AndroidStudio, GooglePixel 3XL Phone (IRL), are updated
- Invalidated/Restarted my Cashes in Android Studio
- The issue also occurs when migrated to AnrdroidX
- All Android phones work as expected when using the emulator, just not the USB Debugging on my physical Google Pixel 3XL
- UPDATE: I got it to work on my Samsung Galaxy 7 through USB!
- Other layouts like Empty Activity/etc all work fine, even in the same project

I made a new Navigation Drawer Layout Activity in Android Studio and added this:

1) Build.gradle (Module:app) dependencies:
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

2) In my Android Manifest:    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

3) An ImageView to my content_main

4) In my MainActivity's onCreate:
Picasso.with(this).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/ek-5vIz_gDw/0.jpg").into(imageView)

```
// MainActivity without the additional override functions (no changes)

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    Picasso.with(this).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/ek-5vIz_gDw/0.jpg").into(imageView)

}
```

And my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not getting any error messages on run, only the image just doesn't load in USB Debugging IRL.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: So I was able to get it working on all other physical phones I tried it on. However To get it to work on the Google Pixel 3XL, I had to make this change. Not sure why it is any different, but it does work!

I was doing this before (Did not work only my physical Pixel 3):

```
    val imageLink = video.link
    Picasso.with(context).load("http://img.youtube.com/vi/$imageLink/0.jpg").into(imageView)
```

Not sure why, but here's the solution that works:

```
    val imageLink = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/${video.link}/0.jpg"
    Picasso.with(context).load(imageLink).into(imageView)
```

Hope this helps anyone in the same predicament!